# How to use different names for logs depending upon attempt to run the application?

Tags: java, logging

I have successfully wrote logs in to a file like this.

```
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className.class.getName());
    FileHandler fh;   
    fh = new FileHandler("C:/className.log");   
    logger.addHandler(fh); 
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);
```

But when i am using "C:/newFolder/className.log" then again i am getting logs on console. How to fix it.

And i want to name my log file according to attempt to run the application. How to achieve that? Kindly help.... Thanks in advance

Comment: there may be a space between `new` and `folder` as i remember window default naming for a dir `newFolder` ...just an idea.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan not working. Is there a necessity to make a directory first then use?

Comment: OoH! yes, and why do you not try?..makdir first and give a proper name without space then try.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan working   Thanks....  how to name the logs based on attempts to run the application?

Comment: *how to name the logs based on attempts to run the application?* Not understood Sorry

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i named my log as className.log, when i run my application again and again it gets replaced always. I want to keep all logs. For that i want to name it depending upon no: of attempts to run the application. how to do it?